# What is the significance of a constant, $C$ in a damped cosine function?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, gravitational-waves, wavelength, gravitational-wave-detectors

I've used to fit some scattered points by an equation of damped cosine with a constant function ($(A\cos({kx})+C)e^{-Bx}$) and that equation fits better than only a damped cosine $A\cos({kx})e^{-Bx}$, where $A$ is the amplitude and $B$ is the damping constant. Due to the high level of scattering, I got good fit by employing a damped cosine with a constant $C$ value.

If we simplify the first equation, there are two terms i.e., $(A\cos(kx)+C)e^{-Bx} = A \cos({kx}) e^{-Bx} + Ce^{-Bx}$

Here is the link of the problem implementation in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505628/possible-approaches-of-curve-fitting-of-a-damped-cosine-function-regression. In the link, the distance in meters is represented along $X-axis$ and the coherence between the sensors is represented along $Y-axis$.

## Description of the physical system:

Let, there are $n$ number of sensors and the sensors are positioned at various distances. Each sensor collects seismic data periodically. So, I've found the real part of coherence (not the magnitude squared coherence) between sensors and plotted these values against the distances. Later, I try to fit those values against the sensor distances (Euclidean) with the help of a damped cosine function. Real part of coherence between any sensors is obtained by the following equation

$RPCoh_{xy} =$ real part of $  C_{xy}/ \sqrt(C_{xx}.C_{yy})$

where, $C_{xy} (f)$ is the cross-spectral density between $x$ and $y$, and $C_{xx} (f)$  and $C_{yy} (f)$ the auto-spectral density of $x$ and $y $ respectively.

My question is what is the physical meaning/significance of the constant $C$ in the above equation and the constant value is decaying w.r.t. distance (Meter)? What is the property of the physical system to have for which the system satisfies the first equation? Any justification or detail analysis is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing the context of the problem and what you're trying to model it's literally impossible to answer this question. If you can update your question with relevant information then you'll be able to get an answer.

Comment: @Niall; I've updated the question with an example implementation link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505628/possible-approaches-of-curve-fitting-of-a-damped-cosine-function-regression

Comment: The constant $C$ could be an offset to the cosine function which also decays at the same rate as t5he cosine function but there is no justification to say that this curve fit function is correct other than it is supposedly better than the other curve fit function.  To give any reasonable answer to your question one needs to know much more about how the data was obtained.  A description of the physical system and the sensors which monitored the system would help.

Comment: @Farcher, thanks for your comment. In a seismic field, which constant value decay exponentially w.r.t. distances. If the majority of seismic field is influenced by the Rayleigh wave, then does the value of $C$ originated from Rayleigh wave or something else? I'm confused about this constant term which is decaying along with distance $x$.